# Multiprocessing error : self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent) AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'calc_square' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>

Tags: multiprocessing, attributes, attributeerror

I am trying to write simple code in shared memory in multiprocessing. I am getting errors. Please help me to solve this.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def calc_square(numbers, q):
    for n in numbers:
        q.put(n*n)

def calc_cube(numbers, q):
    for n in numbers:
        q.put(n*n*n)



if __name__ == "__main__":`enter code here`
    numbers = [2,3,5,7,9,10]
    numbers2 = [2,3,5,7,9,10]
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    q2 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=calc_square, args=(numbers,q))
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=calc_square, args=(numbers2,q2))
    time.sleep(0.05)
    p.start()
    p1.start()
    p.join()
    p1.join()
    while q.empty() is False:
        print(q.get())
    while q2.empty() is False:
        print(q2.get())
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'calc_square' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'calc_square' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

Comment: what is your environment?

Comment: sounds like you're trying to use juypyter or another "notebook" like environment. This is similar to running python in interactive mode, which has some incompatibility with multiprocessing. Instead write a standard .py script and execute it from the terminal with the python executable